# Ecto grandparent key on nested children

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

An `organization` has many `users`

```
schema "organizations" do
  field :name, :string
  has_many :users, TestApp.User
end
```

A `user` has many `subordinates`

```
schema "users" do
  field :name, :string
  belongs_to :organization, TestApp.Organization
  belongs_to :manager, TestApp.User,
    foreign_key: :manager_id
  has_many :subordinates, TestApp.User,
    foreign_key: :manager_id
end
```

How do I ensure subordinates have an `organization_id` value when they are created in the following manner?

```
  test "create Org and User and Subordinate in one step" do
    subordinate =
      %User{}
      |> User.changeset(%{name: "A Subordinate"})

    manager =
      %User{}
      |> User.changeset(%{name: "A Manager"})
      |> Changeset.put_assoc(:subordinates, [subordinate])

    organization =
      %Organization{}
      |> Organization.changeset(%{name: "An Organization"})
      |> Changeset.put_assoc(:users, [manager])

    %{users: [ %{subordinates: [subordinate]} = manager]} = organization = Repo.insert!(organization)

    # Passes
    assert manager.organization_id == organization.id
    # Fails
    assert subordinate.organization_id == organization.id
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option1**
Invoke Repo.insert! on every changeset separately

```
subordinate =
  %User{}
  |> User.changeset(%{name: "A Subordinate"})
  |> Repo.insert!

manager =
  %User{}
  |> User.changeset(%{name: "A Manager"})
  |> Changeset.put_assoc(:subordinates, [subordinate])
  |> Repo.insert!
```

Create helper function that returns list of managers merged with their subordinates

```
defp managers_with_subordinates(managers) do
  Enum.reduce(managers, [], &(&2 ++ [&1] ++ &1.subordinates))
end
```

then pass result to put_assoc

```
users = managers_with_subordinates([manager])

organization =
  %Organization{}
  |> Organization.changeset(%{name: "An Organization"})
  |> Changeset.put_assoc(:users, users)
```

and change your pattern matching to

```
%{users: [user1, user2]} = organization = %Organization{} |> Organization.changeset |> put_assoc(:users, x) |> Repo.insert!

assert user1.organization_id == organization.id
assert user2.organization_id == organization.id
assert user2.manager_id == user1.id
```

**Option2**

```
subordinate =
  %User{}
  |> User.changeset(%{name: "A Subordinate"})
  |> prepare_changes( fn(changeset) ->
    manager = changeset.repo.get(User, changeset.changes.manager_id)
    changeset |> cast(%{organization_id: manager.organization_id}, [:organization_id])
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but for anyone who is struggling with creating nested records on Phoenix Ecto. can make use of Ecto.Multi's run or merge function.

You can read more in the official documentation [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#run/5).

For this problem, you can use this snippet:

Ecto.Multi.run or "Ecto.Multi.merge"

```
Ecto.Multi.new()
   |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:organization, Organization.create_changeset(%Organization{}, organization_params))
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:subordinate, fn %{organization: organization} ->
      User.create_changeset(%User{}, %{
        name: "A Manager",
         organization_id: organization.id
      }))
       |> Ecto.Multi.run(:manager, fn _repo, %{subordinate: subordinate} ->
     Users.create_changeset(
             name: "A Subordinate",
             subordinate_id: organization.id
          )
        |> Ecto.build_assoc(:subordinate)
        |> Repo.insert
   end)
|> Repo.transaction
```